# Mpdf feature Fast Web View

Tags: php, mpdf

I've tried looking for this on google, and on github and here on stackoverflow.
But without success.
Does anybody know if there is a way to activate the Fast Web View on PDF's made with mpdf/mpdf?
I've got a website with quite some pdf files, which are pretty slow in loading.
and i was hoping that if Fast Web View was activated on generating them with mpdf this would help.

Thanks :)

Comment: From what I can gather, this is not just a simple “flag” that gets set on a PDF, but the whole structure of how the data is arranged within the document needs to be different. So I rather doubt that mpdf has anything like that implemented; this would probably be a rather complex feature to implement, so if they had done anything like that, then surely it would be prominently documented …? (Guess/gut feeling.)